# Remove new lines except when preceded by specific set of characters

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed, regex-negation

How can I remove new lines using **Perl** and / or Sed at the bash command line but avoiding a specific set of characters?

The closest I came from this is:

```
perl -C -i -p -e 's/[^.:]\n//' ~/Desktop/bak2
```

The above code is working well on avoid removing lines ended with a dot or a colon, but its failling because when removing the correct new lines its also erasing the very last character of the string. I also would need the removed  \n to be substituted by a space.

Would be great, if possible, to have this solution by Perl and also by Sed.
I've searched for a similar solution in perl or sed and I haven't found it,sorry if it does exists.

Examples:

Existing content:

> Violets are blue and
>
> Buda has great teachings.
>
> Programming can be easy because:
>
> Stackoverflow exists,
>
> and the community always helps
>
> a lot.

Desired output:

> Violets are blue and Buda has great teachings.
>
> Programming can be easy because:
>
> Stackoverflow exists, and the community always helps a lot.

Comment: Post some sample data with the expected result, please.

Comment: The answer you accepted for sure doesn't output expected result.

Comment: Yes, it worked, just added a space at the substitution part:
perl -C -i -p -e 's/(?<=[^.:])\n/ /' ~/Desktop/bak2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may preserve pre new-line match (I added "empty" lines handling):

```
perl -C -i -p -e 's/(^|[^.:])\n/$1/' ~/Desktop/bak2
```

or use positive look behind

```
perl -C -i -p -e 's/(?<=[^.:])\n//' ~/Desktop/bak2
```

Comment: Really thanks, it worked after adding a space on the substitution part: perl -C -i -p -e 's/(?<=[^.:])\n/ /' ~/Desktop/bak2

Comment: @Gabz Replacing new line ("\n") by space wasn't specified as requirement.  You get no more than you ask for :-)

Comment: Yes, I now, sorry for that, I'm a newbie in a lot of aspects. But I'm glad to be learning. Really thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With sed

```
sed -e ':A;/[^.:]$/{N;bA' -e '};y/\n/ /' ~/Desktop/bak2
```

or gnu sed

```
sed -z 's/\([^.:]\)\n/\1 /g' ~/Desktop/bak2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -i pe 's/[^.:]\K\n/ /' ~/Desktop/bak2
```